# I have to run sudo dhclient -v after every startup after update

Tags: dns, dhcp

After I updated ubuntu I have been running into several problems, from losing all my gnome packages to now having DNS issues after each reboot. I need to run sudo dhclient -v for my internet to work every time I open my pc or it won't work, as DNS is failing. Other solution was to add nameserver 8.8.8.8 to resolv.conf but I don't want to use a fixed DNS server but to use DHCP to choose the one to use. Any help is pretty much appreciated!

Comment: `$ sudo apt-get reinstall isc-dhcp-client` ?

Comment: Does not work, I still have to do it. I am also having problems at mounting my hard disks

Comment: Then I can only suggest you solve that problem first, this might actually be a secondary effect (caused) by that fact.